# What is the equivalent of @RunWith(Enclosed.class) in JUnit 5?

Tags: junit4, junit5

What is the equivalent ExtendsWith annotation for @RunWith(Enclosed.class) in JUnit5?

Comment: What does the Enclosed runner do? To answer your question you’ll have to provide more information.

Comment: The Enclosed runner binds together a couple of inner nested classes.

Comment: Inner classes as test groups are supported by default in JUnit 5. Just add a "@Nested" annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `@Nested` annotation in your sub-classes, according to the [JUnit5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested).

Example

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Stack;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@DisplayName("A stack")
class TestingAStackDemo {

    Stack<Object> stack;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("is instantiated with new Stack()")
    void isInstantiatedWithNew() {
        new Stack<>();
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("when new")
    class WhenNew {

        @BeforeEach
        void createNewStack() {
            stack = new Stack<>();
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("is empty")
        void isEmpty() {
            assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("throws EmptyStackException when popped")
        void throwsExceptionWhenPopped() {
            assertThrows(EmptyStackException.class, stack::pop);
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("throws EmptyStackException when peeked")
        void throwsExceptionWhenPeeked() {
            assertThrows(EmptyStackException.class, stack::peek);
        }

        @Nested
        @DisplayName("after pushing an element")
        class AfterPushing {

            String anElement = "an element";

            @BeforeEach
            void pushAnElement() {
                stack.push(anElement);
            }

            @Test
            @DisplayName("it is no longer empty")
            void isNotEmpty() {
                assertFalse(stack.isEmpty());
            }

            @Test
            @DisplayName("returns the element when popped and is empty")
            void returnElementWhenPopped() {
                assertEquals(anElement, stack.pop());
                assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
            }

            @Test
            @DisplayName("returns the element when peeked but remains not empty")
            void returnElementWhenPeeked() {
                assertEquals(anElement, stack.peek());
                assertFalse(stack.isEmpty());
            }
        }
    }
}
```